# Copy artifacts from an upstream multi-branch pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have the following Jenkins setup:

1. A multi-branch pipeline which sometimes (on certain tag builds) triggers
2. a pipeline that builds an installer from the upstream artifacts.

In the upstream MB-pipeline, I have the following fragments:

```
options {
    copyArtifactPermission('my-downstream-project');
}

post {
   success {
       script {
           if (isRelease()) {
               build job: 'my-downstream-project'
           }
       }
   }
}
```

The downstream pipeline, I then try to grab the artifacts:

```
copyArtifacts projectName: 'my-upstream-project', 
              selector: upstream(),
              filter: '*.jar',
              fingerprintArtifacts: true
```

While the downstream build is started, it fails with:

> ERROR: Unable to find project for artifact copy: hds-access-code-cache
>   This may be due to incorrect project name or permission settings; see help for project name in job configuration.

My understanding so far:

- While I can't configure the Copy Artifact permission via the configuration UI for the MB-pipeline, the option is accepted and should work.
- The examples I can find would use `projectName: 'my-upstream-project/tag-name'` as that's the *actual* job. I don't have a fixed branch or tag, though.

How can I correctly access the upstream artifact?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to pass down the job name as parameter.

Change the upstream pipeline to:

```
build job: 'my-downstream-project',
      parameters: [string(name: 'upstreamJobName', value: env.BRANCH_NAME)]
```

Add the parameter to the downstream pipeline:

```
parameters { 
    string(name: 'upstreamJobName', 
        defaultValue: '', 
        description: 'The name of the job the triggering upstream build'
    )
}
```

And change the copy directive to:

```
copyArtifacts projectName: "my-upstream-project/${params.upstreamJobName}", 
              selector: upstream(),
              filter: '*.jar',
              fingerprintArtifacts: true
```

Et voila:

> Copied 1 artifact from "My Upstream Project » my-tag" build number 1

Comment: Nice solution, Raphael. Looks like jobs are now able to infer upstream job info from currentBuild.upstreamBuilds (reference: https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-support-plugin/pull/49). I don't have time to keep searching for documentation on the format of this new variable, so I'm going to "brute force it" using your solution. :-)

Also, I noticed you defined a text param in the downstream job and pass it as a string param from the upstream job. Was this intentional? Are these compatible?

Comment: @timblaktu Good pointer! If you end up figuring that out, please add another answer!

Comment: @timblaktu Um ... it's been a while, so I don't know if I may have messed up anything copy-pasting it here. It seems that, today at least, both `build.parameters` and `parameters` support both `text` and `string`. It's plausible that they are compatible (the difference is probably only to inform UI choices?) but it would definitely be better form if they were the same. Editing, thanks!

Comment: I will note that, IIRC, the issue here was that multi-branch pipelines construct a job name based on branch/tag/whatever, and _that_ part wasn't inferenced at the time.